# How to get new releases from the Apple Music API

Tags: spotify, apple-music

Recently Apple Music launched a [new feature](https://beebom.com/enable-apple-music-in-app-notifications-new-releases/) that notifies the user about new releases. I'm trying to find a way of receiving this notifications from the API, or somehow listen to a set of artists in case of new releases.

If you know any work around or a similar solution using Spotify's API or any other music platform, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For Spotify at least you can use the [Get a List of New Releases](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/browse/get-list-new-releases/) from the Spotify API to request the latest releases, each of the **Album** Objects returned would contain the **Artist** Object for those, there's plenty of ways depending on your programming language of choice to get this information and to **Authenticate** so you can look for those for Javascript, C#, Python etc and see if they will help do what you need.